# Getting an error while testing a Lambda function for Alexa Smart Home Skill, Missing Authentication token

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have created a lambda function and added a trigger to an Alexa Smart Home Skill. It was working fine but when I try to test it now, it gives an alert on top like this : [image: For the lambda function]

I have not enabled authentication anywhere, can someone help me out as to why I am getting this error

Comment: Are you use API gateway by any chance?

Comment: No, I am not using API Gateway. I get the same error when I try to create a new lambda function

Comment: Can you please copy your ARN again from Lambda and configure it in your Alexa trigger?